# Adding more "AND" conditions to FOR LAST causing performance issue

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm new to progress 4GL. I'm trying to find last record from a table. But its causing performance issue. I directly copied my query here so it should be syntax error. Please help me to modify the logic or give me suggestion.

Note - Syntax(USE-SYNTAX) available only for following fields but not sure adding this to for last is good idea.

pc_domain,
pc_list_classification,
pc_list,
pc_curr,
pc_prod_line,
pc_part,
pc_um,
pc_start

```
                for last pc_mstr no-lock   
                    where pc_domain   = global_domain   
                    and pc_list_classification = 1
                    and pc_curr     <> ""
                    and pc_part     = b_ps_mstr.ps_comp
                    and pc_um       <> ""   
                    and (pc_start  <= v_end[v_i]
                    or  pc_start   = ?) 
                    and (pc_expire >= v_end[v_i]
                    or  pc_expire  = ?) 
                    and (pc_amt_type = "L"   
                    or  pc_amt_type = "P"):             
                end.
                if not available pc_mstr then
                do:
                   for last pc_mstr no-lock   
                       where pc_domain   = global_domain    
                       and pc_list_classification = 1
                       and pc_curr     <> ""
                       and pc_part     = b_ps_mstr.ps_comp
                       and pc_um       <> ""
                       and (pc_amt_type = "L"   
                       or  pc_amt_type = "P"):             
                   end.
                end.
```

Comment: please post your indexes on the table pc_mstr

bsp: (pc_start  <= v_end[v_i] or  pc_start   = ?) ist without a index
or pc_curr     <> "" also

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with last? Do you mean LAST as in what Progress means:

> LAST Uses the criteria in the record-phrase to find the last record in the table that meets that criteria. The AVM finds the last record before sorting.

Or do you mean something else? Like the last record created? Depending on what you mean you might have to do different things.

Some pointers about performance though:

Basically where clauses using = is good, >, <, >=, <=, BEGINS etc is decent and <>, NOT is BAD.

But it also boils down to what index you can use. You need to know about the indices of the table! But regardless of indices: those `<>` will make you unhappy. They will cause "table scans" (the entire table will be read).

`<> ""` could perhaps be replaced with `> ""` in this case - a little less evil.

Also you need to use () in a better way with those or's. Otherwise you might not get what you want. OR will win over AND so A AND B OR C really is run as (A AND B) OR C. Maybe you really ment A AND (B OR C) - in that case you need to use those ( ) wisely.